# Spring Boot + CometD + CorFilter: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors

My Project is Spring Boot 1.5.19 & Spring Security 4.2.6 & CometD 3.0.9. 
In the UI side log is : CometD Subscribe Failed.
In the Services Back-end log is : org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
Location is CorsFilter.java : chain.doFilter(req, resp);

This error seems doesn't impact functions, login and handshake and meta/connect always OK. However, Cometd Subscribe Failed and the page always refresh then the new data will return. This isn't what I want. I want to achieve realtime data.I don't know the SecurityContext Error is the reason of this problem or not.

```
@Component
@Order(0)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

Hope no errors and CometD realtime data run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's just my fault.
In the CometdAuthenticator

```
@Autowired
private List<AbstractCometDSubscribeVoter> voters = Collections.emptyList();
```

add the @Autowired, everything works well.